# spring cloud data flow component collisions

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I just started to use the spring cloud dataflow project.

I tried creating some custom components using the spring initialr that was recommended at http://start-scs.cfapps.io

I am finding that quick a few of the components selected are colliding

For example, I generated one that had the following two starters

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud.stream.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-rabbit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud.stream.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-file</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The error I get is (with the nifty spring boot 1.4.0 diagnostics) is

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

There is a circular dependency between 2 beans in the application context:
    - fileSourceFlow defined in org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.file.source.FileSourceConfiguration
    - org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.rabbit.sink.RabbitSinkConfiguration
    - amqpChannelAdapter
```

I also found that the file and rabbit components were not even brought in unless I did an explicit import of their configuration files.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(
        {
                FileSourceConfiguration.class,
                RabbitSinkConfiguration.class
        }
)
public class CommonfileingestorApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CommonfileingestorApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, you can't have a source and a sink in the same app - what are you trying to build?

Comment: I wanted to read a file from a directory and push it on a rabbit MQ queue.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, I generated one that had the following two starters

Unlike typical Boot starters, the stream and task starters are meant to be used as standalone applications, so you can do customizations on them individually. If you'd have to compose multiple applications as one composite unit, you'd have to use the `AggregateBuilder` API - see this [sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/master/double/src/main/java/demo/DoubleApplication.java#L31).

> I also found that the file and rabbit components were not even brought in unless I did an explicit import of their configuration files.

Yes - please review the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/1.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_using_the_starters_to_create_custom_components) for the customization steps.

Comment: I interpreted the starter in the post that was referenced as a way to build custom applications much as the regular spring boot initializr online app.  Apparently it can't be used that way